# copy database structure without data in mysql (with empty tables)

Tags: mysql, copy, database-schema

Is there any way to copy database structure without data in MySQL, so the new database will be the same as it is copied from, but with empty tables.

After getting some suggestions I tried the command, but I am getting syntax error, my `username = root` and `password = nothing`. I guess the default one. I am trying following command,

```
mysqldump -u root -p -d xyz_db | mysql -u root -p -Dnew_db
```

what I am missing or misplacing in command?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
mysqldump -u user -ppass -d olddb | mysql -u user -ppass -D newdb
```

The new database must already exist. The `-d` flag in the mysqldump command prevents copying of data.

There's no space between the flag `-p` and the password.

Comment: I am getting syntax error,my username is root and password is nothing this is my command, mysqldump -u root -p -d xyz_db  | mysql -u root -p -Dnew_db. something wrong with my command?

Comment: be good if you could exclude the password here and enter it on prompt

Comment: @jimmcnamara is it possible to output it to a `.sql` file? such as `mysqldump -u user -ppass -d olddb | mysql -u user -ppass -Dnewdb > newdb.sql` ?

Comment: MySQL server returns an error message starting with "DROP command denied to user" which is nosense while a copying action. Why DROP when creating a new database ? There must be something wrong with the arguments.
I gave a downvote because the DROP permission might not be wanted and the solution is add "--skip-add-drop-table" parameter which you should have included already.

Comment: you may have to use -h parameter to copy between different hosts

Answer (score 11):

You can take backup using **mysqldump** and restore with **mysql** using commandline.

**For backup database**

```
$ mysqldump -u root-pPassword -P3309 --routines --no-data testdb > "d:\dbwithnodata.sql"
```

**For restoration of database**

```
$ mysql -u root-pPassword -P3309 newdb < "d:\dbwithnodata.sql"
```

Comment: there is a problem with triggers and routines that use `testdb`.tb_name so before step 2
 must : 



[#bash    sed -i 's/testdb/newdb/g' dbwithnodata.sql ]

Answer (score 3):

From [electrictboolbox.com/mysqldump-schema-only](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysqldump-schema-only/):

Dumping the database structure for all tables with no data
Add the -d flag to signify that no data should be included in the output like so, where "mydatabase" is the name of the database to dump, and "someuser" is the login name used to connect to the database. The following command will dump the table structure for all tables in the specified MySQL database:

```
$ mysqldump -d -u someuser -p mydatabase
```

The -d flag says not to include data in the dump. Alternatively you can use --no-data instead if you find that easier to remember:

```
$ mysqldump --no-data -u someuser -p mydatabase
```

The -u flag indicates the username and the -p flag that a password will be supplied. After pressing  you will be prompted for the password.

Alternatively, the password can be supplied on the command line, but there must be no space between the -p flag and the password. For example, if the password was "apples" do this:

```
$ mysqldump --no-data -u someuser -papples mydatabase
$ mysqldump -d -u someuser -p mydatabase > mydatabase.sql # This will output to a sql file
```

Answer (score 3):

You can backup you MYSQL database structure with

```
mysqldump -u username –p  -d database_name > backup.sql
```

(You should not supply password at command line as it leads to security risks.MYSQL will ask for password by default.)
And you can create create tables in database with

```
mysql -u username -p new_database < backup.sql
```

Now you can use pipe to give the output of first command as output for second one and you will no longer need `backup.sql`

```
mysqldump -u username –p  -d database_name|mysql -u username -p new_database
```

All tables in will be created in `new_database` without data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$ mysqldump --no-data -h localhost -u root -p database_name > imported_db_name.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

`mysqldump -d` is not enough because in TRIGGERS, PROCEDURES etc. you can have references like `'old_db'.tb_name` that must be replaced with `'new_db'.tb_name`

```
mysql -u user -ppass -e "CREATE DATABASE new_db" 

mysqldump -u user -ppass -d old_db |     # pull structure  -d flag  
sed "s/\`old_db\`\./\`new_db\`\./g" |    # solve foreign_keys, triggers etc 
sed 's/AUTO_INCREMENT=[0-9]\+/''/g' |    # reset indexes
mysql -u user -ppass new_db              # push structure
```

---

below is a bash script that also creates target database and perform some checks

> **# ./db_clone.sh  *old_db*   *new_db***

I use a file `/root/.mysqlcnx`  with credentials (instead of using -u root -pPass)

```
[client]
user = root # or powerfull_user with GRANTS 
password = pass_string
host = localhost
```

and the following script to clone a database  *[ experiment it on a virtual machine for confidence ]*

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
   echo "syntax:\n.\db_clone.sh source_db_name target_db_name [--drop]\n"
exit 1
fi

    # checking target database $2 exits
tg_db=$(mysql --defaults-extra-file=~/.mysqlcnx -s -N -e "SELECT count(*)>0 FROM 
         information_schema.SCHEMATA where SCHEMA_NAME='${2}'")
if [ $tg_db = '1' ]; then
    # checking target database has tables
    tg_tb=$(mysql --defaults-extra-file=~/.mysqlcnx -s -N -e " SELECT count(*) > 0 
            FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='${2}'")
  if [ $tg_tb = '1' ]; then
     if [ $# -eq 3 ] && [ "$3" = '--drop' ]; then
        echo "TYPE 'YES' (case sensitive) TO OVERRIDE"
        read opt # request confirmation 
        if [ "$opt" != "YES" ]; then
            echo "OPERATION CANCELED!"
            exit 1
        fi
     else
       printf "DATABASE \"${2}\" EXISTS AND HAS TABLES\nUSE --drop as 3rd arg to override!\n"
       exit 1
     fi
  fi
else 
  mysql --defaults-extra-file=~/.mysqlcnx -e "CREATE DATABASE \`${2}\`" 
fi

echo "CREATING ${2}"
mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=~/.mysqlcnx -d $1 | # dump source
sed "s/\`${1}\`\./\`${2}\`\./g" |  #  solving `source_db`.tb_name       
sed 's/AUTO_INCREMENT=[0-9]\+/''/g' | # solving  AUTO_INCREMENT=1
mysql --defaults-extra-file=~/.mysqlcnx $2  # populating target_db 
echo "DONE"
```

Comment: disgusting looking code

Comment: sorry :)) ...  you are welcome to make it better looking

Comment: everything  above mysqldump can be excluded   --- all it counts is using sed to avoid triggers+procedures conflict  and reset auto_increment

Comment: is my bad. I was referring to the latest code block and for some reason I thought was PHP and immediately say is disgusting ( and I still believe it would if it was php  I was going too fast and I probably I had hit my daily dose of code saturation) but I notice now is shell script which pretty much can't look any better. Actually +1 cuz is a good answer. She'll script can't look that good and is OK since you are not gonna write applications with it, but languages where we write app code I find outrageous if is not good looking.

Answer (score 0):

As the manual says in Copying Databases you can pipe the dump directly into the mysql client:

```
mysqldump db_name | mysql new_db_name
```

If you're using MyISAM you could copy the files, but I wouldn't recommend it. It's a bit dodgy.

Integrated from various good other answers

Both mysqldump and mysql commands accept options for setting connection details (and much more), like:

```
mysqldump -u <user name> --password=<pwd> <original db> | mysql -u <user name> -p <new db>
```

Example : `mysqldump -u root -pmypassword old_database | mysql -u root -pmypassowrd new_database`

[bloglink](https://php-scripts-form.blogspot.com/2021/05/mysql-cloning-mysql-database-on-same.html)